# How does WolframAlpha derive series representations for $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

Given this [formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28-1%29%2Fsqrt%28-1%29)

$\pi = \frac{\log(-1)}{\sqrt{-1}}$

How does WolframAlpha derive these other series representations?

The only one I recognize is the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for $\pi$

$$4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{1+2k}$$

[image: pi]

Comment: I don't think that the series representations are related to this particular way of expressing $\pi$. If you ask WolframAlpha about $4 \arctan 1$, you get all the same summations as well, for example.

Comment: Good observation about $4 \arctan(1)$. Thanks.